# convert a floating point to corresponding integer

Tags: c

I have sine function(taking sample value =4096 for one sine wave). I want the corresponding float to be converted to integer value.Float value comes like .001534 hex like 3AC90FD6 and corresponding int value as  986255318. When i try to plot the graph its coming for all float values but not for integer values .....

This is logic I have used....and scale cannot be done like multiplying value to 100 like that is not acceptable... please help me out i am new to c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<math.h>

union { 
  float         f;
  unsigned char b[sizeof(float)];
  long          g[sizeof(float)];
} v;

int main(void)
{
  float temp,d;
  int r;
  temp = ((2 * M_PI) / 4096);
  size_t i;

  for(i = 0; i < 4096; i++)
  {
    d = sin (temp * i );
    v.f = d;
    printf("\n %f \t %X", v.f, ( ( v.b[0] ) | ( v.b[1] << 8 ) | ( v.b[2] << 16 ) | ( v.b[3] << 24 ) ));
    printf(" \t %d \n",((  v.g[0]   ) | (  v.g[1] <<  8  ) | ( v.g[2]  << 16  ) | (   v.g[3] <<   24   ) ));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour. Don't use unions. The purpose of unions isn't what you think it is.

Comment: This: `long g[sizeof(float)];` makes no sense at all; if `sizeof (float)` is four it will give you an array of four `long`s, but of course that doesn't overlap the single `float` any more.

Comment: You need to better explain what you're trying to do, with examples. It's currently very unclear.

Comment: I want to send this value to a RTL register so i cannot send a float value right??....so i was wondering how then i change them to an integer

Comment: `long g[sizeof(float)];` will allocate an array of 4 longs in most current systems which probably isn't what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a float to its corresponding integer, you should not simply take the bits and re-interpret them as an integer.

Simply do:

```
int i = (int)myFloat;
```

That will cause a conversion to happen from the internal format of `float` to an `int`. The fractional part of the `float` will be truncated, so it will round down toward 0.

### EDIT

Since your values are the result of a sinus call, they will be in the [-1.0f, 1.0f] range. If you want to have values in the [-4096, 4096] range, simply do:

```
int i = (int)(4096 * myFloat);
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants to do, though.

Comment: Since his float is the result of `sin`, this will convert almost all values to 0. I'm not sure what he's actually trying to do though.

Comment: `(int)(4096 * myFloat);` converts [1/4096 ... 2/4096) to 1, [2/4096 ... 3/4096) to 2, [3/4096 ... 3/4096) to 3, etc. So each 1/4096 range of `myFloat` converts to a single `int`.  This is true _except_ for [-1/4096 ... 1/4096] which converts to 0.  This range is 2x all others.  For greater uniformity, recommend `int i = (int) roundf(4096 * myFloat);`.

Comment: You are right. The range that truncs to 0 is indeed twice that of the others. But round would leave two smaller ranges at the edges.